# localStorage.getItem('token') acts strange

Tags: angular, authorization, bearer-token

I have this code that should return details regarding the connected user. The problem is that when I send the request, the token seems to not be correct and the token value from localStorage is deleted.

```
const tokenHeader = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')});
return this.http.get(AppSettings.URL, { headers: tokenHeader });
```

The thing is that my token is correct and if I hardcode the value I gen from localStorage.getItem('token'), it works correctly.  E.g

```
const tokenHeader = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Bearer ' + 'the token value from localStorage.getItem('token')')});
return this.http.get(AppSettings.URL, { headers: tokenHeader });
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: how and when do you save the token to localStorage? What happens if token is not already saved when making the first request?

Comment: also note that localStorage only saves strings

Comment: I save the token value when I do the user login.  
        localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
The value saved inside the localStorage is correct, because the same value it allows me to do the request from Postman or from the code if hardcode what I get from reading it (I printed the value I got and wrote it by hand in the header and the request worked just fine).

Comment: easy, console.log the token you get from localStorage when making the request. it is possible it is not yet accessible or some other synchronisation issue. The logging will help you find out

Comment: I did this and the printed token is correct. That's what I don't understand because the header should be just correct since the localStorage returns a string

Comment: how did you log it? Did you log the token or the full string `'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')`? try logging both

Comment: What do you mean by `the token seems to not be correct `? What's the token value then?

Comment: I printed it both ways. This is the result

`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc2VySUQiOiIxMWQwZWY1My0zOGZkLTQ3NDAtOTNlMi1kZjIxYmI5YTNjZWEiLCJuYmYiOjE1ODg0MDkyNzMsImV4cCI6MTU4ODg0MTI3MywiaWF0IjoxNTg4NDA5MjczfQ.ahXWCQ8GDw_IkZadzaK-EFc-gLwx4n5haF9lek5Kyw4 `

`Bearer  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc2VySUQiOiIxMWQwZWY1My0zOGZkLTQ3NDAtOTNlMi1kZjIxYmI5YTNjZWEiLCJuYmYiOjE1ODg0MDkyNzMsImV4cCI6MTU4ODg0MTI3MywiaWF0IjoxNTg4NDA5MjczfQ.ahXWCQ8GDw_IkZadzaK-EFc-gLwx4n5haF9lek5Kyw4 `

But when I do the request it returns 401 Unauthorized

Comment: But when I copy the token and paste it by hand, it works correctly

Comment: is your app have different sub-domains?

Comment: no, that's not the case

Comment: ASre you sure you do the exact same request when you hardcode the token? Maybe you do a different request. Also try logging the headers with the hardcoded token and see if they match. Most probably you do a different request when you hardcode the token that is not same as other request which fails, since the token seems to be the same

Comment: I only replace the localStorage.GetItem('token') with what I get from the log, so it should be the same

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you pass it to the separate variable. For instance:

```
let headers = {};
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
if (token) {
  Object.assign(headers, {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
  })
}
```